# PowerApps: Adding/Modifying/Using Connector Not Working

Tags: powerapps

We are unable to use Connectors in Power Apps, also we are unable to add new Connection also. I got below errors while trying to fix/add connection.

[image: Adding Connection Error]

[image: Connection Error]

[image: Error in Power App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to some internal Issue. Now its resolved.